# Whmcs add new tab in client area just beside hosting informaion tab

Tags: whmcs

I need to add new tab in client area of whmcs just beside the hosting information tab 
template for that particular section is located under 
/templates/six/clientareaproductdetails.tpl but I don't want to modify the template file directly.
I have tried creating provisional module by adding mymodule_ClientArea method but that also doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ClientAreaProductDetailsOutput](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/output/#clientareaproductdetailsoutput) hook to output javascript to add the tab.

```
add_hook('ClientAreaProductDetailsOutput', 1, function($service) {
    $code = '';
    if (!is_null($service)) {
        $code .= '<script>';
        $code .= 'console.log("Service ID: ' . $service['service']->id . '")';
        $code .= '</script>';
    }
    return $code;
});
```